# What does prime-to-p-part mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ramification

> What does prime-to-p-part mean ?

[image]

Comment: Divide $e$ by $p$ as many times as possible and you’re left with the prime to $p$ part of $e$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p^a$ exactly divides $e$ (i.e., $p^a$ divides $e$ but $p^{a+1}$ does not; written $p^a \mid\mid e$ ),

then the prime-to-$p$ part of $e$ is $e/p^a$.